# Firebase phone auth kotlin wont send verification code

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I am trying to use firebase phone auth in my
app with an emulator. I have a testing number set up in firebase, but everytime i try to send a verification code, I get the same error: PhoneAuthProvider: Sms auto retrieval timed-out. how do i fix this?*

```
    class PhoneAuth : AppCompatActivity() {
        private var verificationIdGlobal: String? = null
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_auth)
        b_phone_send.setOnClickListener {
        val phoneNumber = et_phone_phone.text.toString().trim()

    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber, // Phone number to verify
        60, // Timeout duration
        TimeUnit.SECONDS, // Unit of timeout
        this, // Activity (for callback binding)
        callbacks) // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}
    b_phone_sign_in.setOnClickListener {
        val verificationCode = et_phone_verification_code.text.toString().trim()
    verificationIdGlobal?.let {
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(it, verificationCode)
        addPhoneNumber(credential)
    }
}}

private val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
    override fun onVerificationCompleted(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        phoneAuthCredential.let {
            addPhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential)
        }
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onVerificationFailed(exception: FirebaseException) {
        Log.d("phone", "$exception")
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun onCodeSent(verificationId: String, token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
        super.onCodeSent(verificationId, token)
        verificationIdGlobal = verificationId
    }
}

private fun addPhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential: PhoneAuthCredential){
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.updatePhoneNumber(phoneAuthCredential)?.addOnCompleteListener {task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful){
            Log.d("Phone", "task successful")
        }
        else{
            Log.d("Phone", "${task.exception}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you didn't copy the code from the documentation that allows for whitelisted numbers to work.  If you think you did this correctly, please edit the question to describe what you did to set this up.

Comment: I don't know what code is required for this as it does not really explain it in the documentation.  Is there anyway you could send me a link to it?  (I have added the test numbers in firebase already)

Comment: oh sorry nevermind i found it

Comment: i will add the code and get back to you thanks

Answer (score 0):

as per my understanding, if you added a phone number as a test number in Firebase console then it will never send a SMS to it, if you did so, then make sure you remove the number from test numbers list in firebase console >> Authentication >> Sign-in method >> Phone >> Phone numbers for testing, then try sending verification SMS to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable developer options and restart your smartphone.  Now collect the project and install it on your smartphone, you will receive SMS.